# To create circle and box as mentioned in below picture

Tags: css

I want to create a box with a circle (whose center is at the top-right corner of the box) placed on top of the box, like in the below picture:

[image]

I know how to create a circle and a box but I want to overlap one the other and their overlapping region should not show the border. How could that be done?

Could anyone please tell me in which way it will be easier to create. either by css or using javascript. And if possible guide me with  coding also.

Comment: I very rarely ask this question but have you tried anything? Circles and rectangles are among the most easiest shapes that can be created with CSS.

Comment: you are right, but i want to overwrite any one on another one.. and their overwriting region should not show the border. how could that be possible

Comment: Now what you have asked in comment is a good question. How about you making this question your actual question and show the code where you have placed a circle on top of a rectangle (with the overlapping region showing the border)? That way your question will not get downvoted (it wasn't me by the way) and not be closed.

Comment: SVG is your best option here by far.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment Paulie_D.. i will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

littel bit difficult.but try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 .circle{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius: 150px;
  
 }

 .rectan{
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left:150px;
  top: 150px;
 }

 .white{
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: white;
  border:2px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: -1px;

 }
</style>
<body>
 

 <div class="circle"></div>
 <div class="rectan">
  <div class="white"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

using image is the best I think

Answer (score 0):

It can be created in this way using absolute positioning

```css
.rect {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.fixrect {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="fixrect"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can find the pen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzdVBQ)

Comment: Thanks yaar... And your name seen to be the name of latest android version "MARSHMALLOW". nice..!